# socket connection over multiple server instances

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, openshift

i have a `node.js` app running on [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) which uses sockets (socket.io) to send messages to connected clients. 
everything works fine as long as there is one only `gear`, as soon as more than one gear gets started i get an

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mydomain.com:8443/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1415998622711-3&sid=u2zNUigydEEhM0vsAAAA. Invalid HTTP status code 400
```

i believe this happens because every gear that starts creates a new socket instance.
does anybody have experience with this scenario?
would the socket.io redis adapter help to solve this issue?